# AWS CodeBuild cannot generate test report 'Skipping invalid file path build/test-results/test'. Why is the path invalid?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codebuild

my buildspec.yml is

```
version: 0.2

phases:
  pre_build:
    commands:
      - cd my-service/
      - gradle clean
      - echo "prebuild complete!"

  build:
    commands:
      - gradle test
#      - gradle bootJar
      - echo "prebuild complete!"

  post_build:
    commands:
      - echo "commence post_build"
      - cd build/test-results/test
      - ls -al
      - cd ../../..
      - pwd
      - echo "post_build complete"

reports:
  unit-test-reports:
    files:
      - '**/*'
    base-directory: build/test-results/test
    discard-paths: no

artifacts:
  files:
    - 'build/libs/*.jar'
```

as you will see I added some additional commands that are not really necessary just to prove that the path is valid.

output is below.

```
Tail logs

Show previous logs
[Container] 2021/01/22 17:08:06 Waiting for agent ping
[Container] 2021/01/22 17:08:08 Waiting for DOWNLOAD_SOURCE
[Container] 2021/01/22 17:08:10 Phase is DOWNLOAD_SOURCE
[Container] 2021/01/22 17:08:10 CODEBUILD_SRC_DIR=/codebuild/output/src353579941/src/github.com/myaccount/myproject
[Container] 2021/01/22 17:08:10 YAML location is /codebuild/output/src353579941/src/github.com/myaccount/myproject/my-service/buildspec.yml
[Container] 2021/01/22 17:08:10 Processing environment variables
[Container] 2021/01/22 17:08:10 Expanded report group name unit-test-reports
[Container] 2021/01/22 17:08:10 Found report group name unit-test-reports
[Container] 2021/01/22 17:08:10 Adding prefix Build-myproject for report group name unit-test-reports
[Container] 2021/01/22 17:08:10 No runtime version selected in buildspec.
[Container] 2021/01/22 17:08:10 Moving to directory /codebuild/output/src353579941/src/github.com/myaccount/myproject
[Container] 2021/01/22 17:08:10 Registering with agent
[Container] 2021/01/22 17:08:10 Phases found in YAML: 3
[Container] 2021/01/22 17:08:10  POST_BUILD: 6 commands
[Container] 2021/01/22 17:08:10  PRE_BUILD: 3 commands
[Container] 2021/01/22 17:08:10  BUILD: 2 commands
[Container] 2021/01/22 17:08:10 Phase complete: DOWNLOAD_SOURCE State: SUCCEEDED
[Container] 2021/01/22 17:08:10 Phase context status code:  Message: 
[Container] 2021/01/22 17:08:10 Entering phase INSTALL
[Container] 2021/01/22 17:08:10 Phase complete: INSTALL State: SUCCEEDED
[Container] 2021/01/22 17:08:10 Phase context status code:  Message: 
[Container] 2021/01/22 17:08:10 Entering phase PRE_BUILD
[Container] 2021/01/22 17:08:10 Running command cd my-service/

[Container] 2021/01/22 17:08:10 Running command gradle clean
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 incompatible and 1 stopped Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details
> Task :clean UP-TO-DATE

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 18s
1 actionable task: 1 up-to-date

[Container] 2021/01/22 17:08:32 Running command echo "prebuild complete!"
prebuild complete!

[Container] 2021/01/22 17:08:32 Phase complete: PRE_BUILD State: SUCCEEDED
[Container] 2021/01/22 17:08:32 Phase context status code:  Message: 
[Container] 2021/01/22 17:08:32 Entering phase BUILD
[Container] 2021/01/22 17:08:32 Running command gradle test
> Task :compileJava
> Task :processResources
> Task :classes
> Task :compileTestJava
> Task :processTestResources NO-SOURCE
> Task :testClasses

> Task :test
2021-01-22 17:08:56.386  INFO 196 --- [extShutdownHook] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Shutting down ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 24s
4 actionable tasks: 4 executed

[Container] 2021/01/22 17:08:56 Running command echo "prebuild complete!"
prebuild complete!

[Container] 2021/01/22 17:08:56 Phase complete: BUILD State: SUCCEEDED
[Container] 2021/01/22 17:08:56 Phase context status code:  Message: 
[Container] 2021/01/22 17:08:56 Entering phase POST_BUILD
[Container] 2021/01/22 17:08:56 Running command echo "commence post_build"
commence post_build

[Container] 2021/01/22 17:08:56 Running command cd build/test-results/test

[Container] 2021/01/22 17:08:56 Running command ls -al
total 40
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root  4096 Jan 22 17:08 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root  4096 Jan 22 17:08 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 23616 Jan 22 17:08 TEST-com.myproject.myprojectservice.MyServiceApplicationTests.xml
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   470 Jan 22 17:08 TEST-com.myproject.myprojectservice.controllers.StatusControllerTest.xml
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  4096 Jan 22 17:08 binary

[Container] 2021/01/22 17:08:56 Running command cd ../../..

[Container] 2021/01/22 17:08:56 Running command pwd
/codebuild/output/src353579941/src/github.com/myaccount/myproject/my-service

[Container] 2021/01/22 17:08:56 Running command echo "post_build complete"
post_build complete

[Container] 2021/01/22 17:08:56 Phase complete: POST_BUILD State: SUCCEEDED
[Container] 2021/01/22 17:08:56 Phase context status code:  Message: 
[Container] 2021/01/22 17:08:56 Preparing to copy TEST report unit-test-reports
[Container] 2021/01/22 17:08:56 Expanding base directory path:  build/test-results/test
[Container] 2021/01/22 17:08:56 Assembling file list
[Container] 2021/01/22 17:08:56 Expanding build/test-results/test
[Container] 2021/01/22 17:08:56 Skipping invalid file path build/test-results/test
[Container] 2021/01/22 17:08:56 No matching base directory path found for build/test-results/test, skipping
[Container] 2021/01/22 17:08:56 Phase complete: UPLOAD_ARTIFACTS State: SUCCEEDED
[Container] 2021/01/22 17:08:56 Phase context status code:  Message: 

Error in UPLOAD_ARTIFACTS phase: [unit-test-reports: [report files not found in build]]
```

I am trying to view the junit test results report generated by gradle.
CodeBuild seems able to read the path to the test report files in the post_build phase.
But when it comes to generating the report, it says the path is invalid

the error claims to be
[Container] 2021/01/22 17:08:56 Expanding build/test-results/test
[Container] 2021/01/22 17:08:56 Skipping invalid file path build/test-results/test
[Container] 2021/01/22 17:08:56 No matching base directory path found for build/test-results/test, skipping

Hope someone can spot something, I have tried everything I can think of.

Answer (score 3):

The problem was a difference between the location of my buildspec.yml and the value of environemnet variable CODEBUILD_SRC_DIR

by running a command

echo $CODEBUILD_SRC_DIR

I noticed that CODEBUILD_SRC_DIR is the root of the repo that was checked out
but my buildspec was not in the root of the repo, it was one directory down.

$>repos/my-project/my-api-service/buildspec.yml

i was using paths relative to the location of my buildspec.yml

$>repos/my-project/my-api-service/build/test-results/test

so i was using just
build/test-results/test epic fail

changed it to be relative to root of repo
my-api-service/build/test-results/test pure genius

now I have beautiful junit test reports

Comment: This was it. Thanks Rory